# jquery window.open in ajax success being blocked

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery

Trying to open a new browser window in my ajax success call, however, it is blocked as a popup.  I did some searching and found that a user event needs to be tied to the window.open for this to not happen.

I also found this solution where you open a blank window before the ajax then load the url as normal in the success call.

So with this I have two questions :

1 - Is this the only solution because I would prefer not to open this blank window.

2 - If this indeed is the only way then how can I load my html into this new window?  For example, if my ajax does not succeed, how can I add my error text into this blank window since the url will not be opened?

I should also note that I do not want to make the ajax call synchronous... this defeats the purpose of ajax and I believe this is going to be deprecated if not already... correct me if I read wrong in my searching.

```
    $('#user-login').on('click', function () {
        var $form = $(this).closest('form');
        window.open('about:blank', 'myNewPage');

        $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: '/spc_admin/process/p_user_login.php',
            data: $form.serialize(),
            dataType : 'json'
        }).done(function (response) {

            $myElem = $('#user_login_message'); //performance for not checking dom
            $myElem.fadeOut('fast', function(){

                if (response.success)
                {
                    $myElem.html('<p><b class="text-blue">Success!</b> &nbsp;You have been logged in as \'<b>'+response.username+'</b>\' in a new browser window.</p>').fadeIn('fast');                 

                    // open new window as logged in user
                    //window.open('http://www.example.com/');
                    window.open('http://www.example.com/', 'myNewPage');
                } 
                else
                {
                    $myElem.html('<p><b class="text-red">Error!</b> &nbsp;Please select a valid user from the dropdown list.</p>').fadeIn('fast');
                }               
            });
        });
    });
```

**EDIT:**

For anyone interested... here is the solution I came up with.  A name is required for the new window so successive clicks will open in the same window and not open new ones repeatedly.  Adding html is a little different than given in the answer and this works.  Blurring of the window does not work so it is not there.  From what I could find this is not controllable and is a browser thing.

```
    $('#user-login').on('click', function () {
        var $form = $(this).closest('form');

        //open blank window onclick to prevent popup blocker
        var loginWindow = window.open('', 'UserLogin');

        $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: '/spc_admin/process/p_user_login.php',
            data: $form.serialize(),
            dataType : 'json'
        }).done(function (response) {

            $myElem = $('#user_login_message'); //performance for not checking dom
            $myElem.fadeOut('fast', function(){

                if (response.success)
                {
                    // show success
                    $myElem.html('<p><b class="text-blue">Success!</b> &nbsp;You have been logged in as \'<b>'+response.username+'</b>\' in a new browser window.</p>').fadeIn('fast');                 

                    // open new window as logged in user
                    loginWindow.location.href = 'http://www.example.com/';
                } 
                else
                {
                    // show error
                    $myElem.html('<p><b class="text-red">Error!</b> &nbsp;Please select a valid user from the dropdown list.</p>').fadeIn('fast');

                    // add error to the new window (change this to load error page)
                    loginWindow.document.body.innerHTML = '<p><b>Error!</b> &nbsp;Please select a valid user from the dropdown list.</p>';
                }               
            });
        });
```

Comment: instead of open new window after login, Why not just use redirect event using `window.location.href="www.example.com";`?

Comment: It is not after login... this is the admin area where the admin can login as a user.  So opening a new window is the right option as I do not want to lose the admin window.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

For opening a new URL in the window you opened in `onclick`, do the following

1. Store the new window you created in a variable `var newWindow = window.open("","_blank");`
2. Change the location of the new window `newWindow.location.href = newURL;`

One additional thing that can be done to improve user experience is to send the new window to background immediately (`newWindow.blur`) after opening and then bring it in foreground again (`newWindow.focus`) while opening the URL the the new window.

Comment: So essentially what I have in place right now.  Looks like that is the only way to get rid of the popup error.  Now, for user experience as well... is there a way to load html into this new window as I mentioned in the OP... if the ajax fails then I would want to add an error message in this blank window I opened.

Comment: You can give an alert in the new window `newWindow.alert("YOUR MESSAGE");`

Comment: For loading HTML in the new window, you can either load a new URL in the new window `newWindow.location.href= newURL;` or insert the HTML content in the new window `newWindow.document.innerHTML = HTMLContent;`

Comment: This sounds like it will work.  Going to try it here in a few.  Really wish this stupid popup blocker wasn't an issue by just loading it normally like I should be able to... seems dumb to have to do it this way to work around this. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Check out my edit.  I cannot get blur or innerhtml to work with this solution.

Comment: Hi @AkshatSinghal, I tried assigning value of `window.open("","_blank")` to a variable as mentioned in the point 1 before initializing ajax call, But I get that variable's value as `undefined` in Safari browser and so I am unable to change `location.href` after the ajax call. Is there any way?

Comment: @PankitKapadia What is the OS and browser version? Are you able to get it working in Chrome?

Comment: @AkshatSinghal Yes it works well in Chrome browser. It is not working in iOS safari and windows safari as well. Currently not able to check with MacOS safari.

Comment: @PasinduJayanath Which browser/OS?

Comment: @AkshatSinghal Google Chrome/Windows 10 64 bit

Answer (score 17):

Do a `window.open("about:blank", "newPage");` before the AJAX call and then after the call add the URL to the opened window by calling `window.open("http://google.com", "newPage");`.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#user-login').on('click', function () {
    var $form = $(this).closest('form');

    $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: '/spc_admin/process/p_user_login.php',
        data: $form.serialize(),
        dataType : 'json',
        success: function(res) {    
            $myElem = $('#user_login_message'); //performance for not checking dom
            $myElem.fadeOut('fast', function(){
                $myElem.html('<p><b class="text-blue">Success!</b> &nbsp;You have been logged in as \'<b>'+response.username+'</b>\' in a new browser window.</p>').fadeIn('fast');                 
                // open new window as logged in user
                window.open('http://www.example.com/', '_blank');
        } else {
            $myElem.html('<p><b class="text-red">Error!</b> &nbsp;Please select a valid user from the dropdown list.</p>').fadeIn('fast');
        }               
    });
});
```

Comment: This doesn't solve the problem, as the browser blocks the window. 

The solution is to invoke the new window BEFORE the ajax, with "_blank" as the href, and then update it after the call returns / fails.