# Displaying POST AJAX Response in new window

Tags: jquery, ajax, pdf-generation

I send POST data through ajax using jQuery and it returns the binary data of a PDF file.

I'd like to do something with this data. Either by providing a link to download, or opening it a new tab/window.

I know sending a user to a website and using GET variables would be easier but there is a lot of data that gets sent through and it needs to be post.

Is there a way I can take the data that I retrieve and let a user download / see it somehow?

```
$("#export_pdf").click(function()
{
    var data_serialize = "v1=blah&var2=again&var3=more_info",
    url = "/actions/export-pdf";
    $.ajax({ 
        type: "POST",
        url: url,
        data: data_serialize,
        success: function(data)
        {   
            // data = PDF binary
            // I want to do something with this
        },error: function(data) { alert("error"); }
    });
});
```

Comment: Take a look at [this answe](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20822711/jquery-window-open-in-ajax-success-being-blocked)r. It resolved my problem.

Answer (score 4):

I am assuming that you are able to retrieve the data and it is being stored in the data variable.

You might try the following in your success function:

```
       //open a new window note:this is a popup so it may be blocked by your browser
       var newWindow = window.open("", "new window", "width=200, height=100");

       //write the data to the document of the newWindow
       newWindow.document.write(data);
```

Another option would be to dynamically create a div that is displayed using your success function in your $.ajax function.

Here is a jsfiddle that will help you if you want to experiment with it:

http://jsfiddle.net/larryjoelane/d8r3su0m/

I have tested another way with the jquery $get function and it works for me. You just have to enable popups.  here is the code I tested. I will attempt it with you ajax function when I get a chance.

```
    $("#load_pdf").on("click",function(){


//swap url with a pdf file you have access to for testing
var url = "http://localhost/Responder Manual.pdf";


$.get(url,function(data){


       //open a new window note:this is a popup so it may be blocked by your browser
       var newWindow = window.open("", "new window", "width=200, height=100");

       //write the data to the document of the newWindow
       newWindow.document.write(data);


});

});
```

Comment: I get `TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'newWindow.document')` with your code

Comment: Try the new code I posted to see if the binary data of your pdf file is then displayed in a pop up window.  Then we will troubleshoot from there.