# How to open a pop-up using JSF without it being blocked by the browser

Tags: javascript, jsf, primefaces, popup, popup-blocker

I'm working on a PrimeFaces 6.0, JSF 2.2 (Mojarra 2.2.7) application.

I need to load a web page from an external site and highlight a DOM node. My approach is to create a JavaScript function to open a pop-up window, load the web page through a servlet (to avoid cross domain issues) and highlight the node. The parameters I send to my function are generated in a managed bean.

I tried to do so in two different ways:

1. Using `RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().execute("myFunction(...)")` in my action (yes, I'm using PrimeFaces).
2. Using `oncomplete="#{myBean.myJsCall}"` on my command button.

Both ways the call is executed and the call is correct, but I run into my browser's (Chromium) pop-up blocker:

[image: The following pop-ups were blocked on this page]

Is there a way to open pop-ups in JSF or specifically in PrimeFaces without them being blocked?

This is not really relevant, but this is the simplified version of my JavaScript function.

I developed this script using plain HTML and JS. There it was opening the pop-up without the blocker interfering. Also, when pasting the call into the console when running the JSF application, the pop-up is opened.

```
function myFunction(url, selector) {
    var popup = window.open("", "popup", "height=500,width=700");
    var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
    req.open("GET", url, true);
    req.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (req.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
            popup.document.open();
            popup.document.write(req.responseText);
            popup.document.close();
            popup.document.addEventListener(
                "DOMContentLoaded",
                function() { /* Some code highlighting the selector */ },
                false
            );
        }
    }
    req.send();
}
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with JSF or PrimeFaces. This is a pure client-side html issue. Better to use a PrimeFaces dialog in this case

Comment: I developed the script using plain HTML / JS. There it was working. Pasting the call into the console also works. Surely you cannot "blame" JSF for this, but I was hoping for a "workaround". A dialog is no option in this case. Content is loaded from an external site and it want to the CSS to mix.

Comment: Opening a multiple popups/opening new windows (which is what you explicitly do) from the same page client-side without user interaction will result in these reponses to (is my experience) Might only be after a few calls. But I doubt you get this message directly when exeuted from a server response. One option I see is to use a plain div and center it in the screen and show the `req.responseText` in there. But if you specifically need a new window then there is not something that comes to my mind.

Comment: OK, thanks. I'll copy some of my action logic to the JavaScript and read the values there so I can use it `onclick`. That was the same scenario I had in plain HTML / JS.

Comment: Good investigation!!!

Comment: Hmm.. `onclick` is also wrapped by PrimeFaces which makes you run into the same issue. Using a plain button does work, but that requires me to inject some extra parameters into the JS call and maybe even a `remoteCommand`. I think a dialog is indeed the way to go. That does require me to use an `iframe` (no big fan of those).

Comment: onclick where? Instead of the oncomplete?

Comment: On a `p:commandButton`. E.g. `onclick="alert('fiets')"` is rendered as `onclick="PrimeFaces.bcn(this,event,[function(event){alert('fiets')},function(event){PrimeFaces.ab({s:&quot;main:j_idt217&quot;});return false;}]);"`.

Comment: I've voted to reopen. I would like to explain what is happening and how to work around this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you try to open a new window in JavaScript, which is not directly triggered by a user action (like a click), but in for example a callback triggered after executing JSF ajax requests, it is blocked by the browser.

This behavior is described in the following question: [jquery window.open in ajax success being blocked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20822711/jquery-window-open-in-ajax-success-being-blocked).

As a workaround you could open a window before the JSF ajax request. In case of a command button using the JSF HTML tags this can be done by using:

`<h:commandButton ... onclick="prepareWindow()"/>`

The `onclick` will be rendered as is. But, when you are using **PrimeFaces**, you **cannot** use:

`<p:commandButton ... onclick="prepareWindow()"/>`

PrimeFaces wraps the `onclick` resulting in indirect execution, so the pop-up is blocked.

Anyhow, with some extra hacks you could get this working with some sort of button which looks like a PrimeFaces button. But the number of hacks was getting too much.

I opted to use a `p:dialog` with an `iframe` instead. To start of, if you are using `p:layout`, **don't** place the dialog in any of the layout units.

The dialog:

```
<p:dialog header="Preview"
          widgetVar="previewDlg" modal="true" width="1000" height="600"
          dynamic="true">
    <iframe src="about:blank"
            class="previewIframe"
            style="position:absolute;top:0;left:0;right:0;bottom:0;width:100%;height:100%;border:0"></iframe>
</p:dialog>
```

The button:

```
<p:commandButton value="Show"
                 ...
                 onclick="PF('previewDlg').show()"
                 action="#{myBean.showPreview('previewIframe')}"/>
```

The action:

```
public void showPreview(String iframeClass) {
    ...
    RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().execute(js);
}
```

The JavaScript function:

```
function myFunction(iframeClass, url, selector) {
    var iframe = $("iframe[class=" + iframeClass + "]")[0];
    iframe.contentDocument.location = "about:blank";
    var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
    req.open("GET", url, true);
    req.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (req.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
            iframe.contentDocument.open();
            iframe.contentDocument.write(req.responseText);
            iframe.contentDocument.close();
            iframe.contentDocument.addEventListener(
                "DOMContentLoaded",
                function() { /* Some code highlighting the selector */ },
                false
            );
        }
    }
    req.send();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

There is an easy way out. Open an empty popup onclick (directly induced by the user, hence not blocked) and redirect the window to the updated model after the ajax data has been submitted:

```
<p:commandButton value="open popup" process="@form"
                     onclick="myNamespace.openPreview()"
                     oncomplete="myNamespace.relocatePreview()"/>
```

This is what your js should look like:

```
myNamespace.openPreview = function () {
    myNamespace.prev = window.open('', '_blank');
}

myNamespace.relocatePreview = function () {
    myNamespace.prev.location = 'preview.xhtml?faces-redirect=true';
}
```

Comment: Have you tried this? When I use `onclick` it's wrapped with a PrimeFaces object (see comments at the question and my answer).