# jquery ajax popup blocked even after made as synchronous request

Tags: jquery, ajax

Within ajax success block, Am trying to use window.open(''). But, browser blocked opening it. By using async:false also, I can't achieve this. How to overcome from this issue.

FYI:
The jQuery version which am using is 1.5.1

Comment: Can be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6628949/window-open-popup-getting-blocked-during-click-event

Comment: Please refer - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20822711/jquery-window-open-in-ajax-success-being-blocked

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jquery window.open in ajax success being blocked](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20822711/jquery-window-open-in-ajax-success-being-blocked)

Comment: Yeah. Thanks for the links. But, for me some cases are there. with in success block, If data is verified only I wanna do this. If data is failed, I wanna show a message in the current window itself.   By default, If I did window.open, For failed cases usability will not be good.