# jquery window.open in ajax success blocked as a popup

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Trying to open a new tab on ajax success using (window.open) function. But it is blocked as a popup specially in iPad (safari browser). There is no user action and just used window.open function.

Can I open this URL in new tab without disabling "block pop-ups" option in iPad.

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: checkDownloadCompleteUrl,
  dataType: 'json',
  async: true,
  data: {
    file: fileName
  }
}).done(function (response) {
  if (response.success) 
    $.each(response.files, function (idx, record) {
      if (record.file_complete == 1) {
        window.open('http://www.example.com/', 'NewPage');
      }
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jquery window.open in ajax success being blocked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20822711/jquery-window-open-in-ajax-success-being-blocked)

Comment: window.open is not a part of jQuery framework. Use modal window instead.

Comment: My fault, I was thinking it was a popup, not a window. Sorry