# How To Open URL In New Tab Using Ajax Success?

Tags: javascript, c#, html, ajax

Here i am trying to open the file in new tab by calling ViewFile action of Doctor controller using Ajax Success which is in function`abc(this)` on click of anchor tag. 
Now the problem is that everything is as required but the url doesnot open in new tab.
Below is my Ajax

```
<script>
function abc(thisEvent) {
    debugger;
    var getDoCredId = $(thisEvent).attr('docCredId');
    var parameter = { id: getDoCredId };
    $.ajax({
        url: "/Doctor/ViewFile1",
        type: "get",
        dataType: "html",
        data: parameter,
        success: function (data) {
            debugger;
            if (data = true) {
                debugger;
                var getdoctorId = $(thisEvent).attr('docCredId');
                var url = "/Doctor/ViewFile/" + getdoctorId;
                window.open(url, "_blank");
            }
            else {
                debugger;
                showNotification("Error", "warning");
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Below is my anchor tag HTML

```
<a title="View Attachment"   docCredId = "' + getDocCredId + '"  onclick="abc(this)"><i class="btn btn-web-tbl btn-warning fa fa-eye "></i></a>
```

Below is code behind

```
public bool ViewFile1(int id)
    {
        var document = _doctorService.GetDoctorCredentialDetails(id);
        string AttachPath = ConfigPath.DoctorCredentialsAttachmentPath;
        string strFileFullPath = Path.Combine(AttachPath, document.AttachedFile);

        string contentType = MimeTypes.GetMimeType(strFileFullPath);
        bool checkFileInFolder = System.IO.File.Exists(strFileFullPath);
        if (checkFileInFolder == true)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
  }
    public ActionResult ViewFile(int id)
    {
        var document = _doctorService.GetDoctorCredentialDetails(id);
        string AttachPath = ConfigPath.DoctorCredentialsAttachmentPath;
        string strFileFullPath = Path.Combine(AttachPath, document.AttachedFile);
        string contentType = MimeTypes.GetMimeType(strFileFullPath);
        bool checkFileInFolder = System.IO.File.Exists(strFileFullPath);  
        bool filedata = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(strFileFullPath).Any();
        byte[] filedata1 = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(strFileFullPath);
        var cd = new System.Net.Mime.ContentDisposition
        {
            FileName = document.FileName,
            Inline = true
        };
        Request.HttpContext.Response.Headers.Add("Content-Disposition", cd.ToString());
        return File(filedata1, contentType);
    }
```

Comment: Where does it open?

Comment: @Nomaed : It doesnot even open anywhere that's the problem

Comment: Is `ViewFile1` action of the `Doctor` controller called when the AJAX request is sended?

Comment: @Alexander : yes and as per specified condition it returns either true or falsebut problem is that even after returning true from ViewFile1 action url does not even open

Comment: Are there any error messages in the browser console? Try to add `console.log(data)` to the success handler.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jquery window.open in ajax success being blocked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20822711/jquery-window-open-in-ajax-success-being-blocked)

Comment: @AminMozhgani: No your duplication for my question does not solve the problem

Answer (score 2):

*Since this is too long for a regular comment, I am posting this as an answer, although it isn't directly going solve the problem because I am not able to reproduce it, but might give some insights and let you check the differences with what happens in your code as compared with this simplified example.*

---

Calling `window.open()` from jQuery ajax success callback works just fine: https://codepen.io/nomaed/pen/dgezRa

I used the same pattern as you did, without your server code but using jsonplaceholder.typicode.com sample API instead.

---

There are some issues with the code sample that you might want to consider, even though you didn't ask for comments about it and it's not directly related to your issue (probably):

1. `if (data = true)` means data will always be true. You probably mean to do a `if (data === true)` if you know it's a boolean value, or `if (data)` if you want to accept any truthy value (true, {}, "something", 42, etc). Judging by the Java code and how you define the response format in the jQuery ajax call, it looks like you're expecting the "data" variable result be an HTML and not a boolean. You might want to try and remove the `dataType: "html"` row and let jQuery set the data format according to what is coming back from the server, and/or send a JSON formatted response, as in a POJO of `{ result: true }` for a successful response. Then make sure that `data.result === true` to be sure that you got what you expect.
2. You should probably add arbitrary data to tags DOM elements the [`data-*` attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes) and if you're using jQuery, access them using the [.data()](https://api.jquery.com/data) selector. White adding just random attributs with string values may work, it's considered an abuse of the HTML and DOM, and the `data-*` attributes are there specifically for adding any data.
3. In the `abc()` function you grab the value of the attribute in the beginning (`var getDoCredId = $(thisEvent).attr('docCredId');`) but in the callback you're trying to get the value once more. You really don't need it since the success() callback is a closure in the scope of the abc() function and it has access to the value already, so doing `var getdoctorId = $(thisEvent).attr('docCredId');` in the callback is really not needed.
4. I'd also suggest naming `getDoCredId` variable just as `docCredId`. Having a "get" prefix usually means that it's a getter function or a reference to some getter. Likewise, the "`thisEvent`" argument of the main function should probably be called "`callerElement`" or something like that since it's not an event, it's an actual element that you're passing directly from the DOM when calling `abc(this)` in the onClick event handler of the `<a>` anchor. This is just to make the code clearer to understand for anyone who's reading it, and for yourself when you're coming back to it several months in the future and trying to figure out what's going on :)

Comment: Since it looks like you aren't going to get an accepted answer you should at least get an upvote for the helpful and spot on suggestions.

Comment: I tried your code in Codepen, and got "Firefox prevented this site from opening a popup window". One way to go around this is to pass the url from the link to the js function as a href attribute.

Comment: You're right. It works on Chrome, but Firefox blocks it. At the time of the function call when clicking on the link, we don't know the value of the href yet since it is dynamic.

Comment: Chrome might also block this action but is a little more tolerant. However, if the server takes to long to answer (in my case I had a breakpoint in the server code), it will also block opening a new tab

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `async: false` to your Ajax request

```
function abc(thisEvent) {
    debugger;
    var getDoCredId = $(thisEvent).attr('docCredId');
    var parameter = { id: getDoCredId };
    $.ajax({
        async: false, // <<<----------- add this
        url: "/Doctor/ViewFile1",
        type: "get",
        dataType: "html",
        data: parameter,
        success: function (data) {
            debugger;
            if (data = true) {
                debugger;
                var getdoctorId = $(thisEvent).attr('docCredId');
                var url = "/Doctor/ViewFile/" + getdoctorId;
                window.open(url, "_blank");
            }
            else {
                debugger;
                showNotification("Error", "warning");
            }
        }
    });
}
```