# Trying to open window.open a page in ajax call response

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax

i am trying to open window.open a page in ajax call response but its not work, but when i removed window.open line and uncomment alert then alert is working.

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/xyz/xyxkk",
    type: 'Get',
    success: function (resp) {
        window.open("https://www.w3schools.com"); 
        //alert('hi');   
        if (resp) {
           
        }
        else {
            alert('Sorry unable to do');
        }
    }
});
```

actually my requirement is page open as window popup

Comment: Give a try to the answer of this question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20822711/jquery-window-open-in-ajax-success-being-blocked

Answer (score 0):

Comment would fit better but not enough reputation, sorry.
Due to the ever lasting battles between browsers and intrusive ads, all js functions that can open new tabs or windows have been severely limited for a long time now. You can't just randomly open new pages or windows.
Generally you can get around this, by 'associating' the window.open to a click event or similar user input. Else your solutions will probably break in the future, even if you get it working for the moment.
Try calling different elements of your code with a .onclick() to see what is allowed. Don't forget to check at least Chrome and Firefox, and also try a few adblockers. If your solution works reliably under all of those you should be good for future adwars to come.